# PhpStorm - how to identify which style rule refers to particular element in editor

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I got particular element in the editor and I want to change color for it but I cant find which rule refers to it in settings.

Is there easy way to find it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than posting a screenshot and pointing to the element in question?

1. Place caret on such element
2. Invoke `Help | Find Action...`
3. Search for `Jump to Colors and Fonts` action
4. Choose most suitable element from the list (if it will be more than one -- which might be based on the language).

[image]

[image]